# how i can apply rule based in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, if-statement

My project is about a color suitable for house. If he choose a type is bedroom and the size is small, the result is light color. Hope you guys can help. I'm new in codeigniter field :). I hope you guys can write for me in view.php, model.php and controller.php

Here is my code in controller

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 
class AutoSuggestion extends CI_Controller {
 
 function __construct()  {  

    parent::__construct();  
      $this->load->library('session');
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->helper('html');
      $this->load->database();
      $this->load->model('AutoSuggestion_model'); 
    
  } 

    public function some_action()
    {
  if (($Type_Name=='Room') && ($Size_Name=='Large'))
  {
    $this->load->view('A');
   }

   else if (($Type_Name=='Room') && ($Size_Name=='Medium'))
  {
    $this->load->view('B');
   }

      else if (($Type_Name=='Room') && ($Size_Name=='Small'))
  {
    $this->load->view('C');
   }

     else if (($Type_Name=='Bathroom') && ($Size_Name=='Large'))
  {
    $this->load->view('D');
   }
   
      else if (($Type_Name=='Bathroom') && ($Size_Name=='Medium'))
  {
    $this->load->view('E');
   }
   
      else if (($Type_Name=='Bathroom') && ($Size_Name=='Small'))
  {
    $this->load->view('F');
   }
   
      else if (($Type_Name=='Kitchen') && ($Size_Name=='Large'))
  {
    $this->load->view('G');
   }
   
     else if (($Type_Name=='Kitchen') && ($Size_Name=='Medium'))
  {
    $this->load->view('H');
   }
   
      else if (($Type_Name=='Kitchen') && ($Size_Name=='Small'))
  {
    $this->load->view('I');
   } 
}
```

here is my code in view.php

```html
<p>ᴥ Please select type of your space ᴥ</p>
<p>
 <input type="radio" name="type" />Room<br><br>
 <input type="radio" name="type" />Kitchen<br><br>
 <input type="radio" name="type" />Bathroom
</p>

<p>ᴥ Please select size of your space ᴥ</p>
<p>
 <input type="radio" name="size" />Small<br><br>
 <input type="radio" name="size" />Large<br><br>
 <input type="radio" name="size" />Medium
</p>
```

Comment: hi, how is the form from the user insert the info and the controller where you call `AutoSuggestion::some_action`

Comment: i dont have any idea. Just try an error to do this assignment :) @elddenmedio

Comment: hi, can you post your form and the controller code,

Comment: I suggest you do the CodeIgniter tutorial first. This is basic CodeIgniter stuff. The code you pasted are just some random if else statements in a method. $Type_Name and $Size_Name are not defined. Nothing is taken from form input. (Also CamelCase and snake_case dont merge). https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html
Doing this will help you way further.

Comment: just updated it. Sorry for this noob question @elddenmedio

Comment: thanks ;) @Clemenz

Comment: we need all the form code and the controller that you call in the `<form action="`

Comment: I dont have that, cause I'm not understand at all about this @elddenmedio

Comment: This won't work. You are referencing $Type_Name in the controller, but your radio button is named "type". You don't have any form handling in the controller, so you're not getting any input from the $_POST array that you can even convert to the correlating variable names. I'm not sure how your logic flow is set up, so I can't suggest an example. Unfortunately, your statement about "help me in model and view" translates to "write this for me". There are some basic concepts here that you need to grasp, but you're going to need to ask more specific questions.